# Explanation of variable

Tags: python

I'm still fairly new to Python and I'm learning about nested dictionaries and nested lists and how to extract values from them. I have an object called `mylst` which has a list of tuples and each tuple has 3 items. Can someone please help explain the following to me so that I understand what is going on with the object `test`?

Thank you.

```
test = [fruit for fruit in mylst if "Lemons" in fruit[2]]
```

Comment: Try searching for `list comprehension` in python. What you can find online would be more useful than anyone answering here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test is a list of tuples. In test only those tuples are present which is having 'Greek' word in the third item of tuples.

Let's take an example

Words = [(hello everyone, may be, I have new friends), ( hey friends, hii, new Greek meaning) , (how is you, traffic means, Greek means) ]

When we run your statement then it will find only those tuples from the words list which is having Greek present in third element of tuples means

Test =[ ( hey friends, hii, new Greek meaning) , (how is you, traffic means, Greek means) ]

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. This helps clarify the test object.

Comment: If it help you to understand clearly then you have to upvote the solution and accept it so that it can be helpful for other peoples who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent using a regular for loop would be the following:

```py
test = []
for data in words:
    if "Greek" in data[2]:
        test.append(data)
```

Look for `python list comprehensions` to understand a little more on their behavior.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. I can see how a regular for loop is equivalent to the test object.